# Result Set closes automatically

Tags: java, bots, discord

I have a problem with my music bot for Discord.
I want to send an embed message when a track ist started, but the ResultSet always closes.
So it can't pass the if-query.

Here is my code (class "TrackScheduler"):

```
try {
                
                file = new URL("https://img.youtube.com/vi/" + videoID + "/hqdefault.jpg").openStream();
                builder.setImage("attachment://thumbnail.png");
                
                System.out.println("4");
                
                ResultSet set = LiteSQL.onQuery("SELECT * FROM musicchannel WHERE guildid = " + guildid);
                
                try {
                    System.out.println("3");
                    
                    if(set.next()) {
                        long channelid = set.getLong("channelid");
                                                
                        TextChannel channel;
                        
                        System.out.println("2");
                        
                        if((channel = guild.getTextChannelById(channelid)) != null) {
                            
                            System.out.println("1");
                            
                            channel.sendTyping().queue();
                            channel.sendFile(file, "thumbnail.png").embed(builder.build()).queue();
                        }                   
                    }

                }
                catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

My LiteSQL.onQuery (class "LiteSQL"):

```
private static Connection c;
    
    private static Statement s;

public static ResultSet onQuery(String sql) {
        
        try {
            
            return s.executeQuery(sql);
        }
        catch(SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return null;
    }
```

Here is the error:

```
ava.sql.SQLException: ResultSet closed
        at org.sqlite.core.CoreResultSet.checkOpen(CoreResultSet.java:76)
        at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3ResultSet.findColumn(JDBC3ResultSet.java:39)
        at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3ResultSet.getLong(JDBC3ResultSet.java:423)
        at de.nameddaniel.bot.musik.TrackScheduler.onTrackStart(TrackScheduler.java:79)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.player.event.AudioEventAdapter.onEvent(AudioEventAdapter.java:72)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.player.DefaultAudioPlayer.dispatchEvent(DefaultAudioPlayer.java:368)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.player.DefaultAudioPlayer.startTrack(DefaultAudioPlayer.java:117)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.player.DefaultAudioPlayer.playTrack(DefaultAudioPlayer.java:80)
        at de.nameddaniel.bot.musik.AudioLoadResult.trackLoaded(AudioLoadResult.java:20)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.player.DefaultAudioPlayerManager.checkSourcesForItemOnce(DefaultAudioPlayerManager.java:443)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.player.DefaultAudioPlayerManager.checkSourcesForItem(DefaultAudioPlayerManager.java:419)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.player.DefaultAudioPlayerManager.lambda$createItemLoader$0(DefaultAudioPlayerManager.java:218)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I'm new here, so if there is any missing information, please tell me.
As well, I'm sorry for the bad formatting.

Greetings, Daniel :)

Comment: What do you mean by always closes? ResultSet is a Closeable object and should close once it falls out of scope, usually in a try-with-resources or try-finally. Post an error if you have one, or more relevant info about the problem.

Comment: I put the error in there. @Jason

Answer (score 5):

## tl;dr

Do not use `static` on your `Statement` and `Connection` fields.

## Details

1. This code **has a security leak**. Look up SQL injection. The basic gist is: Statement is almost entirely useless. You want `PreparedStatement`, and you want your SQL queries to be solely string literals. Don't, ever, 'make the query string' by concatenating user input in. The Query string should be, say, `SELECT * FROM musicchannel WHERE guildid = ?` (yes, with a literal question mark in the string), then use the `setInt` method of `PreparedStatement` to set the guild id. Or better yet, as the JDBC API is not really designed for consumption like this, use something like [JDBI](https://www.jdbi.org/).
2. This is bad exception handling. If you don't know what to do, the right 'I dont know' catch block is `throw new RuntimeException("Uncaught", e);` and not `e.printStackTrace();`. Better yet, have these methods just throw SQLException; methods that obviously do DB things should be throwing that. Note that your main method can (and should) be declared to throw Exception.
3. Connection, PreparedStatement, and ResultSets are all resources and need to be opened via [try-with-resources](https://www.baeldung.com/java-try-with-resources). Not doing so means your app has a leak and will break something if it runs long enough. For DB code, the DB will eventually run out of connections and become entirely inaccessible until you close the java app. That's why you need try-with-resources.
4. You have a single Statement and Connection (the fields are static). Presumably your discord bot can receive more than one message, so if you try to send more than one, the system goes down in flames. Don't use 'static' here. The code you pasted does not itself contain anything that would close your ResultSet, but by redesigning away from static the problem is likely to go away by itself.

Comment: Everything you said is true, but #4 is the actual answer to OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

(Apart from the other answer, which is actually all very good suggestions and you should follow) I presume the following is the problem:

```
            return s.executeQuery(sql);
```

I don't think that will work if it's a static and is being used multiple times by other objects. It will be cleaned up eventually. Rather than doing that there, you should be returning just an object with the data that you need. Look up the DAO class pattern.